# App keeps on stopping

Tags: bug, android-app

Whenever I try to open home option in the Android app, the app shuts down. I tried closing the app from the background but the problem still persists

Comment: I'm afraid us (the site moderators, and users) can't help you much; this is something the developers have to look at (if they ever do — see below). You can help them to help you a lot more by providing more information, such as your phone operating system version and the app version, and ideally a sequence of steps which reproduces the bug.

Comment: That said, I cannot personally recommend using the app to browse SE; it is extremely buggy and has been neglected for years. I do not expect any bugs in the app to *ever* get fixed. Consequently, I do not expect that you will *ever* get a useful response to this. You may as well delete the app and convince yourself that it never existed.

Comment: Now we even don't have to pretend...